Minimize travel time of a group of people with a motorbike

Problem: A group of $n$ people ($n\geq2$) want to travel from A to B but they can only either walk or use a motorbike (fit 2 people) [note that there is exactly $1$ motorbike for them to use]. Given that:
(1) Walking time from A to B of every person is $T_{0}$
(2) Moving time from A to B of the motorbike is $T_{1}$ ($T_{1}<T_{0}$)
(3) Walking speed and motorbike speed are fixed constants
(4) Real life factors are negligible
What is the minimal travel time for all $n$ people to reach B?

Firstly, I will add more conventions:
(1') $p_{0}$ is the motorbike rider and he will not let anyone else ride the motorbike
(2') $p_{1},p_{2},...,p_{n-1}$ are the other $n-1$ people
(3') B is counted as a drop point as well
Here is a known strategy for case $n=3$: $p_{0}$ will carry $p_{1}$ for an amount of time $t$, drop $p_{1}$ somewhere, then turn back to pick up $p_{2}$. Let's say when $t=t^{*}$, the motorbike ($p_{0}$, $p_{1}$) and the walking $p_{2}$ will both reach B at the same time (this way, no time is wasted on waiting). If $t>t^{*}$, $p_{2}$ will reach B first and he will have to wait the motorbike at B. Similarly, if $t<t^{*}$, the motorbike will have to wait $p_{2}$ at B (if $p_{1}$ is not dropped), however, we notice that in this case ($t<t^{*}$), the motorbike can meet $p_{2}$ at A' (between A and B) and the initial problem repeats itself (starting point A changed to A'). From there, we deduce that if the travel time is minimal for some $t<t^{*}$ then the problem has to repeat itself infinitely.
After some calculations, I did verify that $t=t^{*}$ minimizes the travel time:
$$T_{min}(3)=T_{1}\frac{3T_{0}+T_{1}}{3T_{1}+T_{0}}$$
And the drop points (distance from A): $\frac{T_{0}+T_{1}}{T_{0}+3T_{1}}AB, AB$
Now, if I follow the strategy "all reach B at the same time", I can get a general result (I assume):
$$T_{min}(n)=T_{1}\frac{(2n-3)T_{0}+T_{1}}{(2n-3)T_{1}+T_{0}}$$
And all drop points (in this order) are: $\frac{T_{0}+T_{1}}{T_{0}+(2n-3)T_{1}}AB, \frac{T_{0}+3T_{1}}{T_{0}+(2n-3)T_{1}}AB, ...,\frac{T_{0}+(2n-3)T_{1}}{T_{0}+(2n-3)T_{1}}AB$
I conjecture the formula above.
Question: Is my formula correct? Is it really the minimal time, if so, how do we prove it? I attempted to prove it myself but for $n\geq4$, the sensible choices of how $p_{0}$ move are unlimited and I don't know how to deal with infinite-variable problem like this.
[Also, I avoided writing down my calculations because they are really long]
Edit: So it was mentioned in the comments that this is a linear programming (LP) problem, but I'm not sure how it can help me

(1) Nice Calculation & Conjecture ! It looks mostly right. (2) You have given Drop Point $AB$ multiple times : there is only one Drop Point at B , which is the last. Every other Drop Point is not B.

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/111297/five-friends-and-two-motorcyclists/111301#111301

Too long for a comment, but this idea may help to prove your statement:
I think it is quite possible to show that everyone has to arrive at the same time in the optimum. Suppose some walking people arrive at different times (there is really no reason for the motorist to arrive at another time since he should be driving other people around full-time) It is safe to assume that everyone gets to ride the motorcycle at least once. Say that someone with the slowest time arrives later than the person who was on the motorcycle before him. Then the motorcyclist could have dropped the other person off a bit earlier, and drove to the slow person earlier, to reduce the time of the slow person (to make this formal, maybe use induction/extremal principle). The other case would be when someone gets picked up after the slowest person, in which case the slow person could have stayed on the motorcycle a bit longer at the cost of the person after him. So in conclusion, whenever there is a difference in arrival times, you can always improve.
However, one should then still prove that your solution is the fastest out of the possible solutions where everyone arrives at the same time.
